# Controller method not getting called when javascript validation getting passed

Tags: javascript, action

I have a javascript validation on click of command button(onclick="return validationFunc();").
When the validation is failing the backend action is not getting called(which is expected),however the action does not get called when the validation is passing.

```
<apex:commandbutton onclick="return validationFunc();" action="{!backendAction}"/>

function validationFunc(){
//when validation fails
return false;
//when validation passes
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work together. Refer to this answer:
[Visualforce onclick doesn't execute action or rerender](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/visualforce-onclick-doesnt-execute-action-or-rerender)

You would have to create Action Function to achieve desired functionality.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="backendAction" action="{!backendAction}"/> 

<apex:commandButton onclick="validationFunc();"/>
```

JS

```
function validationFunc(){
//when validation pass
backendAction();
}
```